# problem chaining operations on strings modification

Tags: string, postgresql, function

I try to chain operations on strings in columns of a postgresql database. If I do those 2 operations separately it works:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRANSLATE (upper('A BUCHE'),'ÇÀÄÂÉÈÊËÏÎÌÖÔÒÜÛÙ-','CAAAEEEEIIIOOOUUU '), '\y[A-Z]{1}\y', '', 'g'),'LA','','g'),'DE','','g');

select split_part('BUCHE',' ', 1);
```

The first gives BUCHE and the second applied on BUCHE also gives BUCHE.

But when I chain them the result is an empty string

```
select split_part(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRANSLATE (upper('A BUCHE'),'ÇÀÄÂÉÈÊËÏÎÌÖÔÒÜÛÙ-','CAAAEEEEIIIOOOUUU '), '\y[A-Z]{1}\y', '', 'g'),'LA','','g'),'DE','','g'),' ', 1);
```

Do you know what is wrong?

A second question:
I do all this to correct last names and first names before doing some matching. As my table has 15 millions lines, which is better from a performance point of view:

- to chain operation on string like I did
- or to one operation at a time

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer : there was a blank. I added a trim in the chain

select split_part(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRANSLATE (upper('de la a buche'),'ÇÀÄÂÉÈÊËÏÎÌÖÔÒÜÛÙ-','CAAAEEEEIIIOOOUUU '), '\y[A-Z]{1}\y', '', 'g'),'LA','','g'),'DE','','g')),' ', 1);